# Does PayPal support webhooks or Instant Payment Notification for donation buttons?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-webhooks

PayPal's sandbox `Instant Payment Notification (IPN) simulator` appears to be buggy as it doesn't work for me.

I've managed to get webhooks working with sandbox transactions for a `Smart Button`.

Do they also work for donation buttons?  The word `donation` does not appear in any of the webhook event titles or descriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Donations are regular payments with a different checkout UI. Webhooks and the old IPN service will both work.

Comment: Is it as simple as turning my `Smart Button` into a `donation` button with some simple property?  Or do I have to rework the button entirely?

Comment: Smart buttons do not support the Donations flow. Create a Donate button at https://www.paypal.com/buttons if you want that flow.

Comment: Thank you.  I hope they support the `invoice_id` key.  I use it to store sensitive info about the user (as an encrypted string).

Comment: If you want to pass custom variables, in Step 2 uncheck the option to save the button at PayPal, and after generating the code click to remove code protection.  Then you can add a hidden input for e.g. the "invoice" variable, documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/#payment-transaction-variables

Comment: If your created button has no inputs or dropdowns, there will be an "Email" tab with a simple URL, which may be easier to work with than the HTML form

Comment: This sounds perfect! Thank you very much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216680/discussion-between-girkovarpa-and-preston-phx).